# Why does goBack() method of Yii Framework 2.0 always redirect to the backend

Tags: php, redirect, yii2

Below is my `actionLogin()` function in the frontend `SiteController`.

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

After logging in successfully, it always redirects user on the backend. Below is my frontend's `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Other code is as general. Why does it always redirect user to the backend? Where should I look for or watch out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set different sessions for backend and frontend. Here's well explained steps of how to configure your main's config files:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8289

For redirects you should use `$this->redirect`, it's easier to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to find out the reason why $this->goBack() always redirects user to the backend, to understand its behavior better. If you know why, I would like to hear it from you. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: goBack() function redirects you to the return url, see the docs:
[link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#goBack%28%29-detail)
For example, if you log in to backend, log out and then log in to the frontend you'll be redirected to backend. This happens because, without different sessions, the returnURL was set to backend page.